# Possible to specify multiple values for select as query

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

```
SELECT my_col = 'D' AS test FROM db.table;
```

Let's say this is my query.

At the moment, `test` will be either true or false.  However, I want the column `test` to be of value `val_a` if true or `val_b` if false.

Is this possible / how would this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
select
  case when my_col = 'D' then val_a else val_b end as test
from db.table
```